# discord.py : How can I check to see if a user is in the server or not before issuing a ban?

Tags: python, discord.py, member

I'm trying to make it so if one of my moderators go to ban a user, my bot will tell them if the user is no longer in the server if they left before action could be taken against them. This is the start of my ban command:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Head Honcho", "Discord Moderator")
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member is None:
        return await ctx.send("This member could not be found, or you did not provide an ID.")

    if reason is None:
        return await ctx.send("Please provide a reason for banning this user.")

    if user not in ctx.guild.members:
        return await ctx.send("This user is not in the server.")

    if ctx.channel.id == 805651955841236993:
        reaction_emote = ("<:Checkmark:820467149554319410>")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(reaction_emote)
```

The issue I'm having is with this bit here:

```
if user not in ctx.guild.members:
        return await ctx.send("This user is not in the server.")
```

Nothing I'm trying seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually need a check since you have the argument `member` converted to a `discord.Member` object when defining your function arguments. A member object will always be in the guild, so you don't have to worry about getting an invalid user. Now if you'd like to catch the exception, you can do so using the `on_command_error` event.

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        return await ctx.send("This user is not in the server.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a member is not in a channel like [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

```
if guild.get_member(ID_OF_MEMBER) == None:
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

Is there any way to do this without having the input the ID within the line of code since it'll be different for each user that'll be getting the infraction in a server?

Comment: id will always be unique to a user. member.id() to get id of member

Answer (score 0):

I have my own way of doing that.

```
@client.command() # Ban command
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member in ctx.guild.members():
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.mention} is  not a server member!")
    
    else:
        # Do Stuff
```

This will check for member in the server.

Thanks :D

Comment: [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.members) is not a function nor awaitable, it's merely a list.

Comment: @thegamecracks Uh Oh! My mistake